# Why does including a header in C++ (OpenFOAM) cause my program to not run properly?

Tags: c++, header, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openfoam

I have compiled a solver called `reaktoroFOAM` in `OpenFOAM` successfully (in WSL) :

```
#include <Reaktoro/Reaktoro.hpp>
#include "fvCFD.H"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //#include "setRootCaseLists.H"
    Reaktoro::ChemicalEditor editor;
    editor.addAqueousPhaseWithElements("H O C Ca");
    editor.addMineralPhase("Calcite");

    Reaktoro::ChemicalSystem system(editor);

    Reaktoro::EquilibriumProblem problem(system);
    problem.add("H2O", 1, "kg");
    problem.add("CaCO3", 1, "mol");
    std::cout << "h" << std::endl;
    Reaktoro::ChemicalState state(system);
    std::cout << "h" << std::endl;
    state = Reaktoro::equilibrate(problem);
    std::cout << "h" << std::endl;
}
```

And it works perfectly fine:

```
(base) mcrossover97@DESKTOP-E8DM4SE:/mnt/d/FOAM/run/reaktoro$ reaktoroFOAM
h
h
h
```

But when I include `setRootCaseLists.H`, although the solver is made, it doesn't run properly. Since it does not give me any error in WSL, I have no idea what the problem might be. it doesn't print the last "h":

```
(base) mcrossover97@DESKTOP-E8DM4SE:/mnt/d/FOAM/run/reaktoro$ reaktoroFOAM
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
  =========                 |
  \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
   \\    /   O peration     | Website:  https://openfoam.org
    \\  /    A nd           | Version:  8
     \\/     M anipulation  |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Build  : 8-9b73cf21a682
Exec   : reaktoroFOAM
Date   : Nov 05 2020
Time   : 22:25:24
Host   : "DESKTOP-E8DM4SE"
PID    : 10734
I/O    : uncollated
Case   : /mnt/d/FOAM/run/reaktoro
nProcs : 1
sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).
fileModificationChecking : Monitoring run-time modified files using timeStampMaster (fileModificationSkew 10)
allowSystemOperations : Allowing user-supplied system call operations

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
h
h
```

Update: This is the error:

```
#0  Foam::error::printStack(Foam::Ostream&) at ??:?
#1  Foam::sigFpe::sigHandler(int) at ??:?
#2  ? in "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6"
#3  Reaktoro::Regularizer::Impl::assembleEchelonConstraints(Reaktoro::OptimumState const&) at ??:?
#4  Reaktoro::Regularizer::Impl::regularize(Reaktoro::OptimumProblem&, Reaktoro::OptimumState&, Reaktoro::OptimumOptions&) at ??:?
#5  ? at :?
#6  Reaktoro::OptimumSolver::solve(Reaktoro::OptimumProblem const&, Reaktoro::OptimumState&, Reaktoro::OptimumOptions const&) at ??:?
#7  ? at :?
#8  ? at :?
#9  ? at :?
#10  Reaktoro::EquilibriumSolver::solve(Reaktoro::ChemicalState&, double, double, Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >) at ??:?
#11  Reaktoro::equilibrate(Reaktoro::ChemicalState&, Reaktoro::EquilibriumProblem const&, Reaktoro::EquilibriumOptions const&) at ??:?
#12  Reaktoro::equilibrate(Reaktoro::EquilibriumProblem const&, Reaktoro::EquilibriumOptions const&) at ??:?
#13  Reaktoro::equilibrate(Reaktoro::EquilibriumProblem const&) at ??:?
#14  ? in "/home/mohammad/OpenFOAM/mohammad-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/reaktoroFoam"
#15  __libc_start_main in "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6"
#16  ? in "/home/mohammad/OpenFOAM/mohammad-8/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/reaktoroFoam"
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I would be very appreciative if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: why have you decided it doesn't print the third 'h', but not the first? could you please try printing 1, 2, 3?

Comment: btw, it's quite uncommon to include header inside a function? are you sure it's meant to be included this way?

Comment: I tried it and it is the last one:

Comment: you tried what?

Comment: Yes I know it is kinda weird but it is OpenFOAM standard!

Comment: I tried printing 1, 2, 3; 1 and 2 are printed but not 3.

Comment: are you sure `state = equilibrate(problem);` isn't blocking? does your binary finish correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite familiar with C++. would you please explain your question?

Comment: 'blocking' means returning the answer after a particular time period. This time period might be quite long. E.g. sleep function. It's blocking: your program won't do anything further before the sleep call returns. Does it make things clearer?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How can I check whether it is blocked or not?

Comment: Simply saying if your program even finishes or you have to terminate it somehow.

Comment: I was trying to know what the error is. I updated my question with the error. Could it be because of some conflicts between the headers?

Comment: @MohammadKhojastehmehr Try disabling `sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).`